# How to generate DateTime using RestfulAPI Entity Framework DatabaseFirst

Tags: c#, entity-framework, api, datetime, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to generate a current DateTime based on posting a json data through Fiddler
Here is my post data

```
{"Username":"Johnny","Message":"say hello"}
```

My Model

```
 public partial class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    }
```

My Controller

```
public void Post([FromBody] User user)
        {
            using (UserDataEntities entities = new UserDataEntities())
            {

                user.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
                entities.Users.Add(user);
                entities.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

How I can generate DateTime automatically for my model to get current DateTime?

I'm getting an exception

> OptimisticConcurrencyException: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

Answer (score 0):

## OPTION 1:

Given you're using C# 6.0 you can use the cool new feature called [auto-implemented property initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) and do like so:

```
public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; } = Datetime.Now
```

## OPTION 2:

Add a constructor in your model and set the `DateCreated` property in there. Like so:

```
public User() 
{
    DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Comment: It won't work I still get the same exception, It only works when I post parameter DateCreated from json file like this 
 {"Username":"Johnny","Message":"say hello","DateCreated":"2017-08-14T00:00:00"}

Comment: Would you post the exception stack please! I think the problem is not related to the date generation...